# Find the length of...

Tags: geometry

Find the length of $\overline{AD}$ knowing that it is divided into three equal parts by to tangent circles with radius respectively  $3\sqrt{3}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ . Here's the graph: so the segments $\overline{AB}$, $\overline{BC}$ and $\overline{BC}$ are equal. 
[image]
Thank you very much!

Comment: **Help us help you.** What tools are allowed? (Geometry? Coordinates? Vectors? Trigonometry?) How far did you get before you got stuck? Where did you get the problem, anyway? (Textbook? Contest? Your imagination?)

Comment: I've got the problem from a text book. It's geometry. I tried to use the power of a point but I realized then that I have to a system of two equations and three variables. That's all that I did, now I have no ideas.

Comment: The context is helpful. Just mentioning "the power of a point" (one of my favorite notions, by the way :), in particular, gives an indication of your level of skill and the problem's level of difficulty. Anyway ... I don't have a good answer for you (yet?), but I can report that, using an inelegant coordinate-based argument, I found the length of $\overline{AD}$ to be $6\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Can you give me a simple indication how you found it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Let $AB=BC=CD=x$.

$O1M$, $O2E$ $⊥AD$. (Perpendicular bisectors)

$O1MEO2$ - rectangular trapezoid.

$AM=MB$ and $CE=ED$. Hence $ME = 2x$.

From right triangles $O1AM$ and $O2ED$ we got $O1M = \sqrt{R^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}}$ and $O2E = \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}}$

Use Pythagorean theorem for triangle $O1FO2$ ($O2F ⊥ O1M$):

$(\sqrt{R^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}} - \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}})^{2} + (2x)^2 = (R+r)^2$ 
$\equiv$

$R^2  - \frac{x^2}{4} + r^2 - \frac{x^2}{4} - 2\sqrt{R^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}} \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}} + 4x^2 = R^2 + 2Rr+r^2$
$\equiv$

$\frac{7}{2}x^2-2Rr=2\sqrt{R^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}} \sqrt{r^2 - \frac{x^2}{4}}$
$\equiv$

$\frac{49}{4}x^4-14x^2Rr+4R^2r^2=4R^2r^2+\frac{x^4}{4}-x^2(R^2+r^2)$
$\equiv$

$12x^4+x^2(R^2+r^2-14Rr)=0$

Where we get $x=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{3}} \sqrt{14Rr-R^2-r^2} = 2\sqrt{2}$

By condition $AD=3x$. So $AD=6\sqrt{2}$

Comment: Thank you very much Alexander.

Comment: But can you explain me why is O2F the midline of the trapezoid?

Comment: My mistake, sorry. $O2F$ just perpenicular to $O1M$

Comment: Now I understand, thanks